# Get flatten keys from object which may contain function

Tags: javascript, lodash

This is the function which I've found for making keys flat, for example

```
    const keys = flattenKeys({a: { b: 1, c: 1}});
```

Returns

```
{ 'a.b': 1, 'a.c': 1 }
```

But for this input

```
const keys = flattenKeys({a: { b: 1, c: () => {}}});
```

It gives me

```
{ 'a.b': 1 }
```

As we can see `a.c` is missing

```
export const flattenKeys = (obj: Record<string, any> | any[], path: string[] = []) =>
  !isObject(obj) ? { [path.join('.')]: obj } : reduce(obj, (cum, next, key) => merge(cum, flattenKeys(next, [...path, key])), {});
```

I was trying to add `!isObject(obj) && isFunction(obj) ...` but it seems to be not working

Expected output:

```
{
 'a.b': 1,
 'a.c': () => {}
}
```

@Edit:
isObject, reduce, merge comes from `lodash` package

Comment: I've forgot to mention that, those functions comes from `lodash` package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `!isObject(obj) ?` to `!isPlainObject(obj) ?` to exclude only plain objects:

```js
const flattenKeys = (obj: Record < string, any > | any[], path: string[] = []) =>
  !_.isPlainObject(obj) ? {
    [path.join('.')]: obj
  } : _.reduce(obj, (cum, next, key) => _.merge(cum, flattenKeys(next, [...path, key])), {});

const keys = flattenKeys({
  a: {
    b: 1,
    c: () => {}
  }
});

console.log(keys);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```